# How to select everything around a shape in Pixelmator?

Tags: pixelmator

Using Pixelmator, quite often I need to draw a shape and then select everything around that shape to apply a filter or change hue/contrast. Is there an easy way to select everything around a shape, specially when the shape is not a rectangle.

For example, in this blog post, I created a red rectangle with round edges:

https://watuhq.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/exporting-applicants-from-a-job-and-improved-staffer-engagement/

and you can see everything around it is grayish. I got away with it because the rectangle is on top of white, so you can't see the edge, but when the rectangle is on top of something with a color, I need to have the selection perfectly around the rectangle, otherwise it looks broken.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the shape in the layer list to select it.
2. Right click on the shape in the layer list.
3. Click on "Group".
   [image]
4. Select **Edit -> Load Selection**

This will select around the shape itself. If the shape is just a stroke, you might need to use the magic wand or something similar to select/unselect the contents.

Comment: My problem is not inverting the selection, my problem is selecting around a rounded rectangle that was just drawn.

Comment: Select the rounded rectangle shape in the layers pallet. Right click on it and select "Group". Select Edit > Load Selection in the menubar. This will select around the shape itself.